# GSPREAD on Pi : SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)

Tags: python, gspread

I am experiencing a problem with accessing a google drive spreadsheet from my pi with gspread.  Using the following code - I have moved the the python IDLE to try and resolve the issue.

```
>>> import gspread
>>> gc = gspread.login('username', 'password')
>>> spreadsheet=gc.open('Spreadsheet')
>>> Log_sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("Sheet1")
>>> Log_sheet.acell('B1').value
'Value @ B1'`
```

I have tried using the same code in the command line from my computer (checked versions) and it works fine with the result above.  I have updated the version on my pi

The error happens on the pi after the line `>>>Log_sheet = spreadsheet.worksheet("Sheet1")`
so I have logged in and access the google spreadsheet - its accessing the worksheet - it does exist and I can access from my computer.  I have also posted a request for help on the Raspberry Pi site.

Can anyone help?  Here is the error output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/gspread/models.py", line 123, in worksheet
self._fetch_sheets()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/gspread/models.py", line 62, in _fetch_sheets
self._sheet_list.append(Worksheet(self, elem))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.1/dist-packages/gspread/models.py", line 168, in __init__
self.version = element.find(_ns("link[@rel='edit']")).attrib['href'].split('/')[-1]
File "/usr/lib/python3.1/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 305, in find
return ElementPath.find(self, path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.1/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 186, in find
return _compile(path).find(element)
File "/usr/lib/python3.1/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 176, in _compile
p = Path(path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.1/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 93, in __init__
"expected path separator (%s)" % (op or tag)
SyntaxError: expected path separator ([)
```

I have also tried reinstalling elementtree, as I saw this could be a possibility on my search for an answer, I have also tried python 3.1 on the pi, still no joy.

please can anyone help?  I think its something really easy but I am not seeing it

Comment: It's a bug; go to gspread/models.py and change line 168 to read `self.version = self._get_link('edit' , element ).get('href').split('/')[ -1 ]`. Or update gspread.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to incompatible use of ElementTree API in gspread itself and it is [fixed](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/commit/ed1b4df7e4b2692ea0e76a816cd7d8aaee9e5630) in [0.1.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gspread/0.1.0).